# Vue.js v-component on table

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, vue.js, components

In the Vue.js Docs, they say you have to use v-component instead of the direct component-tag when using a component in a table. But this doesn't work:
Do you have any workaround - even with CSS formatting - or fix?

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')
    <div class="table-responsive" id="vueTable">
        <table class="table-striped">
            <thead>
                <td class="table-cell"><strong>Aktion</strong></td>
            </thead>
            <tr v-component="members" class="success" v-repeat="members" inline-template>
                <td>@{{ $data | json }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('footer')
    <script src="/js/vue.js"></script>
    <script>
        var v = new Vue({
            el: '#vueTable',
            data: {
                members: [{
                    prename: 'Deniz',
                    lastname: 'Adanc'
                }]
            },
            components: {
                members: {
                    template: ''
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Comment: If you are using an inline template, don't you need to remove the template attribute from the members component definition? Also, can you reproduce the problem in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 5):

Evan made breaking changes in 1.0 again. After many failed attempts this is the combination of html/javascript that works for me when trying to include custom component in a table (which in turn is another parent component):

HTML file:

```
    <script id="comments-template" type="text/x-template">    
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr is="my-comment" :data="comment" v-for="comment in comments">
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </script>

    <script id="comment-template" type="text/x-template">
        <tr>
            <td>{{comment}}</td>
        </tr>
    </script>
```

JavaScript snippet:

```
    Vue.component('my-comment', {
        template: '#comment-template',
        props: [
            'data',        
        ],
        data: function() {
            return {   
                comment: '',
            };
        },
        ready: function() {        
            this.comment = this.data.comment;
        }
        ...
    });

    Vue.component('my-comments', {
        template: '#comments-template'
        ...
    });
```

There are two components here: `my-comments` (which is a table) and `my-comment` (which is a row/rows in the table). `comment` from `v-for` loop is passed as a `data` property and remapped inside `my-comment` to the actual data of `my-comment` (`this.comment = this.data.comment`).

It looks rather ugly and not completely intuitive but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

I was pulling my hair out trying to fix this one until I realized I did not have the latest Vue.js installed.

Gladly, this issue was found to be a [bug](https://github.com/yyx990803/vue/commit/12c82fe2212166f6d9292d89ac28b75d46e99225) and is fixed on version 12.6 of Vue.js

You can download the latest [here](http://vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) or simply go to vuejs.org

Comment: I suppose the problem is back in Vuejs 1.0.0

Comment: I suppose that would warrant a new question which mentions `1.0.0`